# Android ADT on Windwows 7 64bit

Tags: android, windows-7, eclipse-plugin, adt

I've been having issues with eclipse. I had sucessfully created and tested several apps then I upgraded my Java (I can't remember what exactly) and it all went down hill.

I tried making a hello world app after upgrading and it said can't find .apk so I decided to upgrade my eclipse. Then when I started it up it lost the android ADT so I tried to reinstall it but couldn't add it correctly....so I ran as administrator and it worked, it installed and showed up in Windows > Preferences

Now all my apps, including new ones say "Failed to load properties file for project 'Hello World' and I just can't figure it out

I have tried several versions of eclipse 3.5, 3.6 none seem to work. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Also update sdk as well which may resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

OMG I finally got this darn thing working, I must have spent 8 hours trying different things. This is what I finally did. Hopefully it helps someone, Please keep in mind I am clueless!

Android SDK installer_r08-windows.exe

Java jdk-6u23-windows-x64

Eclipse eclipse-SDK-3.6.1-win32-x86_64

That is what I kept doing wrong apprently, I was installing the eclipse-java but it wasn't working so I tried "Eclipse Classic 3.6.1" and everything worked

Before I ran eclipse I deleted C:\Users\my_username\.android\debug.keystore 
But I don't think that really did anything

Also I ran eclipse as administrator.

I have windows 7-64bit and it feels good to be up and running again!